# Fix database encoded through PDO without specifying UTF8 charset

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, utf-8

Although I set up my web app to be fully compliant with UTF8, I forgot to specify the UTF-8 charset in the PDO settings... It happens that the Chinese characters looks strange in the database/phpmyadmin (ä½ å¥½ for 你好), although they look fine in my web app.

As I finally know the solution (to add the charset in the PDO connection settings), I would like to know if there is an easy way to convert my old data to a proper UTF-8. I found on Stackoverflow the following code that does the job, but it solves the encoding problem column per column, table per table..

```
UPDATE tablename SET
field = CONVERT(CAST(CONVERT(field USING latin1) AS BINARY) USING utf8);
```

Does it exist a way to perform such conversion to the whole database?

I precise that my MySQL databases/tables are already configured to use the charset UTF-8.

Thanks!

Comment: First, let's see `SHOW CREATE TABLE` and `SELECT col, HEX(col) ...` for some mangled text.  That is needed to determine whether it is Mojibake or Double Encoding (which is messier to fix).  See [_this_](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38363567/1766831) for some discussion.

Comment: And, since you are using Chinese, you will need utf8mb4, not just utf8.

Comment: Hello Rick, thanks a lot for your feedback. Here are the results I get: With SHOW CREATE TABLE, I have DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci at the end of my table structure. And for HEX(col), I get long strings starting with C, that seems to be for Western Europe.

Comment: Does the _column_ override the charset and collation?  Instead of having a long string; let's see a substring.

Comment: `你好` is hex `E4BDA0E5A5BD` if correctly stored as utf8; it would be hex `C3A4C2BDC2A0C3A5C2A5C2BD` if "double encoded".  Before attempting to fix the data, we need to distinguish the two cases.

Comment: Thanks a lot Rick for your help. All my columns are set with utf8_unicode_ci, and I confirm my data are double encoded because I get the exact same hex value 'C3A4C2BDC2A0C3A5C2A5C2BD' for 你好.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have "double encoding".  I believe these steps 'caused' it:

1. The bytes (for, say, `你好`) to be stored were correctly encoded utf8 (`E4BDA0 E5A5BD`).
2. The `CHARACTER SET` for the column was correctly utf8 (or utf8mb4).  (It could have been latin1, with same outcome.)
3. The "connection" was set to latin1 when you `INSERTed`.  This is where the error was.  That declared that the data being stored was encoded as latin1, these 6 characters: hex `E4 BD A0 E5 A5 BD`.  During the storing, they were converted to the columns charset (utf8) to become `C3A4 C2BD C2A0 C3A5 C2A5 C2BD`.
4. You correctly `SELECTed` the data as utf8.  But, by now, that gave you this mess:  `Ã¤Â½Â Ã¥Â¥Â½`.

Two things are wrong; both need fixing simultaneously:

- Step 2 needs changing to establish that UTF-8 is the client's encoding.  See [*PHP*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/charcoll#php).  Do something like `$db = new PDO('dblib:host=host;dbname=db;charset=UTF8', $user, $pwd);` for PDO.
- The data needs fixing.  Your `UPDATE` looks good for *this* case.

Comment: For other conversion cases, http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/charcoll#fixes_for_various_cases

Comment: For me, setting `charset=UTF8` wasn´t enough. I had to specify the TDS version, like this: `'dblib:version=7.0;charset=UTF-8;host=host;dbname=db'`

Comment: @StackUnder - I think the use of the dash is wrong in that context.  That is, `utf8` is correct, `utf-8` is not.

Comment: @StackUnder - You are not associated with Pierre, correct?  Please start a new Question, and provide all the details of _your_ situation.  Please include the Hex, `SHOW CREATE TABLE`, `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE char%`, and anything else discussed in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363566/trouble-with-utf8-characters-what-i-see-is-not-what-i-stored .  There is likely to be some subtle difference between your situation ahd Pierre's.